# VTiger CRM customer portal (Cannot connect to Server.Please configure your site url in provided config file.)

Tags: php, apache2, vtiger, vtigercrm

Hi my vtiger customerportal login is not working when I'm changing the config url's set to PUBLIC IP.

When using private ip it let's me login successfully.

```
config.inc.php (http://<private_ip>)
config.template.php (http://<private_ip/customerportal>)
config.php <- customer portal (http://<private_ip/customerportal>)
```

When changing config using the public ip this is the error

```
config.inc.php (http://<public_ip>)
config.template.php (http://<public_ip/customerportal>)
config.php <- customer portal (http://<public_ip/customerportal>)
```

Cannot connect to Server.Please configure your site url in provided config file.

Comment: Make sure customer portal can access VtigerCRM via public ip address.

Comment: Usually you cannot use public ip when your servers are behind NAT. Instead, use your private IP